# kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset

Tags: serialization, retrofit

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.musiclover, PID: 26687
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 8: Expected start of the object '{', but had ':' instead at path: $.items
JSON input: {"items":[{"added_at":"2022-11-30T13:4.....

I have used header in my api like this ------->

```
@Headers(
    "X-RapidAPI-Key: ed09c2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX524433fc",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host: spotifyXX.p.rapidapi.com"
)

@GET("playlist_tracks/?id=XX&offset=0&limit=100")

suspend fun geAlltracks(): Music
```